Is it Possible to Convert Imgs and Videos into 3d Model for virtual tours?
I'm developing a web application using React, Next.js, Node.js, and Python, where users can upload images and videos of properties. I want to create virtual tours by converting these uploads into 3D models (if possible).

Is it feasible to convert images (e.g., multiple angles) or videos (e.g., 360-degree) into 3D models programmatically?
What are the recommended approaches or tools for this process?
Should I consider photogrammetry software, online services, or specific libraries for image processing?

I'm looking for guidance on the best practices for achieving this functionality and any code examples or resources that could help me get started.

Currently working on an Ai project based on "SEM" (meta ai). Basically, sem allows you to segment anything and create an overmask with the poligons of the segmented objects from a custom image. The model is very strong and well defined. I suggest you take a look into it.

I am not an AI person; I am a regular software developer with knowledge of web and app development. Can you please elaborate on your answer a bit? It will help me a lot. Thanks for your time.

as regular dev, i am still reading and learning about this new technology, i am sure that it's a great start for your project but it does require a large deep dive.
Most of my knowledge in this regard comes form the official doc
link
i am sorry if i cannot provide a more in depth analysis but i am still studying the model myself.
hope this will be a good starting point for your project, let me know how it goes

also keep in mind that we are talking about a relatively documented field called photogrammetry, you can find a lot of programs online who can do this process for you altho i am not sure they provide their source code or any api to implement their product on a custom project.
So beside SAM, which i am sure will help you on your journey, you can look for specialized photogrammetry softwares online. Let me know if this also helps
